# why do git reset commit + git push cause tip of current branch to go behind remote?

Tags: git, heroku, github, git-reset

I wanted to undo a couple minor changes on my repo. I decided to go back two commits, and did

```
git reset --hard <commit>
```

and

```
git push -f
```

Everything went through fine. But when I pushed to heroku, I got an error about how some refs weren't pushed, and then this explanation:

*Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.*

Every time I go back to a previous commit, I wind up with a detached HEAD or with the tip behind remote. This prevents me from pushing to git or heroku. Why? How do I get around this? What is the proper list of commands to follow so that this does not cause interference in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that heroku is not allowing you to `rewrite` the history. When you are working on remote branches you shouldn't use `reset` or `rebase`. By using

```
git revert HEAD~2..HEAD
```

2 new commits will be created reverting the changes from the last 2 commits. This also prevents merging conflicts for your co-workers.

Comment: At this point, wouldn't that erase the work I want to keep? I successfully reset to and pushed the commit, so I'm assuming your suggestion would just undo everything I did.

Comment: This will `revert` your last 2 commits as you want, but both of them will remain in history. So if you later decide that you need these 2 commits you can get them. If you use `reset` the 2 commits will not be part of the revision tree anymore (will not remain in history).